# Net48 and NetStandard projects having issues with System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

We are trying to reference a Netstandard2.0 project in a net48 windows application, however we are hitting an error of the netstandard project referencing system.runtime 4.2.2.0 and the net48 app referencing a lower one.

We've tried:

- BindingRedirects in App.Config:
- Adding the latest version of System.Runtime from nuget
- Referencing the package directly from the Targeting Pack

and thus far nothing has worked.

[image]